# How to get the currently invoked process is 32 bit or 64 bit installed application?

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I am running a process using Process class in C# as follows

```
Process p = Process.Start("lync");
```

It opens the Microsoft Lync Application. How will I know that if it is 32 - bit application or 64 bit application.

Based on that I have to create some registry keys.

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/IsWow64Process.html  You might want to think this through for a bit, surely you want to whack those registry keys *before* you start the program.  Chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the second half of the accepted answer covers it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Missed that 2nd half the first time I read it.